# Speeding up Redis on Windows / C#

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

Im experimenting with Redis on my local machine. So far i've got it working albeit *very* slowly.

Ive got an array of about 14,000 objects, and retrieving them is taking just over 3 seconds each time, which is obviously too slow for production purposes.

I have a feeling the majority of the time spent is on de-serializing the objects, but im not really sure if there's anything I can do to correct this.

Can I store them in the first place without serialializing them (if that makes sense)?
Failing that, is there anything I can do to speed up the deserialization process? I've implemented ISerialization but it doesnt seem to make any difference.

For reference im using the ServiceStack adaptation of Redis.

Comment: Are you getting different results with [redis-benchmark](http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)?

Comment: What are the results of persisting the same 14k objects in other data stores?

Comment: Did you try timing the actual de-serialization of the objects? Eg load them all, check current time, de-serialize them, check difference in time. If it is slow, try another serialization-method. BSON is built with rapid serialization/de-serialization in mind, maybe that will work better.

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is that rather than guessing, try profiling your code to find out for sure where the time is spent

Comment: We use MessagePack for serialization to/from redis; reduced read latency by 30-50%, and reduced memory use in redis by 75%.

Answer (score 3):

> Unless you measure, you will not know.
>
> [Source: A wise dev' manager of mine, circa 1992!]

Before pointing fingers at supposed culprits, you should first profile/measure your code to determine exactly where your performance issue is. Then implement a fix and re-measure. Repeat until your perf is satisfactory.

There are many profilers available to use, including [Visual Studio's built-in profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx), others are available as add-ins (e.g. [RedGate's Ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), [JetBrains' dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [Telerik's JustTrace](http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx), etc.)

Alternatively, try using `Trace.WriteLine(...)` and `Stopwatch` to instrument your code in order to work out how long the data access operations take to execute and how long it takes to de-serialize the data.

FWIW, I'd be surprised if a recent build of Redis ran as slowly as you're seeing on Windows or any other OS. Heck, even SQL Server Express (2012) can return 199000 rows and store them in a CSV in less than 1s:
[image]